# I have to calculate LENGTH OF LAST WORD in a string.Getting error

Tags: java, string

I am getting runtime error "String Index Out Of Range".I have to calculate length of last word in a string.

```
class Solution
{
    public int lengthOfLastWord(String s)
    {
        if(s==null || s.isEmpty())
        {
            return 0;
        }
        int count=0;
        int len=s.length();
        s=s.trim();
        for(int i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            if(s.charAt(i)==' ')
            {
                break;
            }
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: For what input? [Works for me](https://ideone.com/9QSNmj)

Comment: Give the broken case may help others understand your problem, and debug step by step may make you solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You calculate the length and then potentially shorten the string by trimming it, making the actual length shorter than `len`.

```
int len = s.length();
s = s.trim();
```

Reverse the order of those operations.